# Example of continuous function on closed and unbounded set in $R$ with no maximum

Tags: real-analysis

What is an example of a continuous function on a closed and unbounded set with no maximum? Is $f(x)=x^3$ a correct example?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is perhaps a simpler example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your example $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,f(x)=x^3$ is correct, since $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and unbounded and $f\to +\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: another good, concise answer

Answer (score 4):

Your example is correct. Simpler might be $f(x) = x$ and maybe more interesting $f(x) = x^{37} + x^{10} +1$, but **not** $f(x) = - x^2$ (why?)

Some other examples:

- $f(x) = -e^{x}$: bounded above by $0$ but has no maximum.
- $f(x) = -e^{-x^2}$: bounded above, assumes its minimum $-1$ at $0$ is bounded above by $0$ but has no maximum.
- $f(x) = \arctan{x}$: bounded above and below by $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ but has neither maximum nor a minimum.

See [the plots by Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-Exp%5Bx%5D%2C+-Exp%5B-x%5E2%5D%2C+ArcTan%5Bx%5D).